# Need approach for developing custom PowerPoint UI: new macros activated from customized ribbon tabs, usable on PC and Mac

Tags: windows, macos, com, powerpoint, powerpoint-addins

## What I'm trying to accomplish

- **Build** a customized set of macros in PowerPoint designed to make it faster and easier to work with
- **Include** a customized set of tabs on the ribbon for activating these macros, each containing associated buttons, with some or all of these buttons containing a small graphic representing its function
- **Deploy** this functionality and associated UI on PCs and Macs in a way that is easily updatable when new functionality is added

## What the problem is

I cannot identify a single best approach for accomplishing all of these objectives among the various ways developers can add functionality to PowerPoint.

**Key detail:** I'm working on a PC with PowerPoint Version 2108

## What I know or have done already

- I know how to program VBA PowerPoint macros in that program's macro editor.  (For what it's worth, I've also done a good deal of development of PowerPoint macros in Python using the pywin32 package.)
- I am aware of the ribbon customization functionality in Visual Studio and have experimented with it.
- I am aware of PowerPoint [add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins), though the breadth of what they can do is not clear to me, despite reviewing the documentation.

My main concern is deploying to Macs: some solutions seem to leverage Microsoft Office COM, which, if my understanding is correct, is not available on Macs, while others that may work with Macs don't seem to let the developer customize the ribbon.  In any case, I've done lots of searching for solutions on the internet, but nothing I've found seems like an obvious fit for what I'm trying to do.

I would appreciate any help you could offer on finding the right direction for this work.  Side note: I would prefer to not rely on any software outside of what Microsoft makes available (Office, Visual Studio, and so on).

Comment: If you're relying only on VBA, pretty much anything that works on the Windows version will work or can be made to work on Mac. Anything you can do in VBA will work when you save the same file as a PPAM (aka add-in). Your original PPTM can include ribbon customizations that can add tabs, groups, buttons etc to the stock ribbon bar. Again, anything you do along these lines in a PPTM will also work when saved as PPAM and will work on Mac.

Comment: By the way, for most practical/useful purposes, ignore the stuff about add-ins in the article you linked to. MS is exercising its propensity to confuse the troops by overloading terminology with multiple meanings. There are COM addins (developed in pretty much any language you like), VBA add-ins (developed in PowerPoint/Excel/Word etc), and add-ins developed in HTML5+CSS+Javascript, which is what that article was referring to. And that, other than in a few specific scenarios, aren't really ready for primetime. Given that and your correct understanding about COM add-ins+MacOS, VBA is it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.